# Displaying more than one content in a UITableView

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

My question is for all the iPhone developers, since I'm new to iPhone I'm struggling a bit.
I have an XML file which has data like this

```
<results>
<from_user_id_str>84092950</from_user_id_str>
<profile_image_url>http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/592722322/GJ_normal.png</profile_image_url>
<text>haguregumo) シリアの悲劇⑨・・・反政府グループ支援＝犠牲者増加の構造… http://t.co/wj6dMcFQ #india</text>
</results>
```

The results tag is multiple in my XML. Now I want to show this content in a UITableView.
I feel that NSDictionary would be the right class to implement here, but I don't know the following:

1. How to convert my XML in a NSDictionary object. I want to do this in MonoTouch.
2. How to display content like images, text, and other buttons in a UITableView.

Any help would be great.

Thanks and Regards
Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @competent_tech (short ;-) answer...

> How to convert my XML in a NSDictionary object. I want to do this in MonoTouch.

Since you selected MonoTouch you should try to stay .NET-ish, e.g. parse your XML using [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) or [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx) or [XLinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx)... lots of options are available in .NET to do this :-)

Also avoid using Objective-C types, like `NSDictionary` unless they are needed by some other API you **need** to use (there are often better .NET alternatives).

E.g. use a generic-based [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) or define your own structures (great match for XML serialization).

> How to display content like images, text, and other buttons in a UITableView.

Using [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can be a bit complex.

Many people, including myself, will encourage you to use [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) instead. It has great sample code, it's easy to customize (you'll find lots of questions **and answers** here on stackoverflow.com) and it will feels much more .NET-ish.

Comment: Hi, can you also tell me, do i need to have a specific version of MonoTouch/MonoDevelop to work with Monotouch.Dialog. Currently my MonoDevelop version is 2.4.2?

Comment: The latest MonoTouch is always the best. The one in beta right now (5.1.1) even includes it's own copy of MonoTouch.Dialog and is made to work (best) with MonoDevelop 2.8.x. OTOH you can always go back (using GIT) to an old MonoTouch.Dialog that will work with old MonoTouch but, in any case, MonoDevelop 2.4.2 is **very** old.

Comment: Hi, i need one more help. 
First question is:
I understood that the sections, text, images, etc on a MonoTouch.Dialog will be created dynamically. But can i have buttons as well? If yes, how can i have the events of that button binded.

Second question is :
Basically i have a search text, and a button, on the click of the button, the text is sent to the Twitter-url, to get the tweets, these tweets need to be displayed, now they contain, images, texts, and reply and a favourite. Can the search result and the Search Button+Edit box, be the part of one ViewController?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma this is not a forum, please review the stackoverflow.com FAQ. In short: one question -> answers (voted up/down, accepted) then more questions (comments are to get more details/clarifying questions/answers). FWIW your first question was asked (and answered), not long ago, in stackoverflow.com (do a search on monotouch.dialog) and a full (open source) Twitter client exists (TweetStation) and is based on MonoTouch.Dialog (google it up).

Comment: Apologising for this...i m new hence did not know how to properly use.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating a class to hold the data from the file, then use MonoTouch.Dialog to render the class in a table view. [Here is a very good](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Feb-23.html) article on the subject.